# How to get type from enum?

Tags: c#

Currently I have this working code

```
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassOne>(message.Content);
```

How do I make the above code dynamic by replacing the hardcoded `ClassOne` with `message.ContentCategory` which stores an enum? How do I convert the enum value `message.ContentCategory` to a type?

```
public enum ContentCategory
{
    ClassOne, ClassTwo
}
```

I tried below but no success.

```
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(message.ContentCategory)>(message.Content);
```

Comment: There is no inherent connection between an enum value and a type in your project, even if the names coincidentally overlap. What are you actually trying to achieve here? See: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The reason I think this might be an XY problem is that even if you can deserialize it to one of these types, how do you plan to use it afterwards?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, I am trying to make the code generic. Otherwise, I have to write many switch case with multiple repeat code as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` type depends on `message.ContentCategory`

Comment: Area the types ClassOne and ClassTwo somehow related (e.g. derived from the same base class)? If not, I don't see how you can avoid many switch/case and ugly casts.

Comment: @KlausGütter, a bit related but they both are different. I plan to serialize them into one property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be a switch statement:

```cs
object content;
switch (message.ContentCategory)
{
    case ContentCategory.ClassOne:
        content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassOne>(message.Content);
        break;
    case ContentCategory.ClassTwo:
        content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassTwo>(message.Content);
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown category: {message.ContentCategory}", nameof(message));
}
```

Failing that, you need some way of determining which class (as a `Type`) the message actually belongs to. If you get that `Type` then you can use it like this:

```cs
Type targetType = DetermineType(message.ContentCategory);
object content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.Content, targetType);
```

This uses [this non-generic overload](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) of the `DeserializeObject` method.

`DetermineType` could look up values from a `Dictionary<ContentCategory, Type>` that contains types that you manually register when the application starts, or it could find a `Type` with that name in the loaded assemblies, etc. It's up to you how that aspect should work.

An example implementation of the `DetermineType` method that scans all namespaces for types declared in the namespace "MyProject.DeserializableTypes" and below, whose name matches the category name:

```cs
public static Type DetermineType(ContentCategory category)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .Where(a => a.IsClass && !a.IsAbstract && (a.Namespace + ".").StartsWith("MyProject.DeserializableTypes.", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == category.ToString());
}
```

Personally I would prefer registering types in some way because there's less room for error that way IMHO.

---

An alternative approach might be to create a custom attribute that allows you to specify the target type on the enum:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class TargetTypeAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public TargetTypeAttribute(Type targetType)
    {
        TargetType = targetType;
    }

    public Type TargetType { get; }
}

public enum ContentCategory
{
    [TargetType(typeof(ClassOne))]
    ClassOne,
    [TargetType(typeof(ClassTwo))]
    ClassTwo
}
```

And then you can lazily build a table of enumValue->Type to use as the `DetermineType` method:

```cs
private static readonly Lazy<IReadOnlyDictionary<ContentCategory, Type>> _targetTypes = new Lazy<IReadOnlyDictionary<ContentCategory, Type>>(BuildTypesDictionary);

private static IReadOnlyDictionary<ContentCategory, Type> BuildTypesDictionary()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<ContentCategory, Type>();
    var enumValues = Enum.GetValues<ContentCategory>();
    foreach (var value in enumValues)
    {
        Type targetType = typeof(ContentCategory).GetField(value.ToString())?.GetCustomAttribute<TargetTypeAttribute>()?.TargetType;
        if (targetType == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Enum {nameof(ContentCategory)} doesn't declare a target type for {value}.");
        }
        dict.Add(value, targetType);
    }
    return dict;
}

public static Type DetermineType(ContentCategory category)
{
    if (!_targetTypes.Value.TryGetValue(category, out var type))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown category: {category}", nameof(category));
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: The solution looks good. Thanks. I like the second solution compared to the switch case solution.